# Can a PowerApps gallery be sorted from a derived column?

Tags: sorting, powerapps-formula

I have a PowerApps gallery that lists data from 3 different tables and have it normally sorted by the following:

```
SortByColumns(Filter(Personnel, !Dismissed, txtMSSearchBox.Text in MemberName), "MemberName", If(SortDescending1, SortOrder.Descending, SortOrder.Ascending))
```

One of the fields is displayed from the below:

```
Last(SortByColumns(Filter(PersonnelEvents, MemberNumber.Id = ThisItem.ID, EventType.Value="Promotion"), "Date", SortOrder.Ascending)).Title
```

What I would like to do is sort the gallery by this derived data.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try making On visible of the screen have an UpdateContext function which saves this formula as a variable.
You can then reference this variable as the column you want to sort by.
i.e something like `UpdateContext({mySortColumn: Last(SortByColumns(Filter(PersonnelEvents, MemberNumber.Id = ThisItem.ID, EventType.Value="Promotion"), "Date", SortOrder.Ascending)).Title})`

I just hope I really understand what you are trying to achieve, but if this doesn't work, maybe you can explain better what you are trying to do and hopefully I'll be able to help

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work.  I'm trying to do this on a gallery and the second formula (the one that begins with "Last") is determined on each record in the gallery.

I have decided to use Flow to update a column in my main table to show the relevant data and thereby sort by that field.  

Thanks anyway for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use Flow to update a column in my main table to show the relevant data and thereby sort by that field.  I believe this would be an easier way to accomplish what I want.